# Linux mail or PHP mail() doesn't reach some addresses

Tags: php, email, sendmail, postfix-mta, spf

I'm trying to get my PHP scripts to send mail using mail() command, which I think uses the linux sendmail or mail command.

I've tried both sending with the PHP mail() and linux command line mail command, but in both cases the mail gets sent, but it only reaches some emails. I've tested with 5 different domains and 3 of them receive the email while 2 of them don't. The mail's don't even go to spam, they just don't arrive at all.

With PHP mail() I am using correct From address header and I can receiuve the mail in my gmail account. When I look at the "original" in Gmail, I can see that everything is okay (spf=pass, etc...)

It just feels like it's some automatic rejection by some receiving servers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: I checked my MTA log file and I found these:

```
Nov 24 08:30:09 ranits postfix/pickup[8484]: 94861EC738: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Nov 24 08:30:09 ranits postfix/cleanup[8555]: 94861EC738: message-id=<20111124083009.94861EC738@mydomain>
Nov 24 08:30:09 ranits postfix/qmgr[7985]: 94861EC738: from=<www-data@mydomain.eu>, size=351, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 24 08:30:09 ranits postfix/smtp[8631]: 94861EC738: to=<name@mydomain.ee>, relay=mh3.elkdata.ee[213.180.31.146]:25, delay=0.35, delays=0/0/0.35/0, dsn=5.5.2, status=bounced (host mh3.elkdata.ee[213.180.31.146] refused to talk to me: 504 5.5.2 <mydomain>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname)
```

and

```
Nov 24 08:28:10 ranits postfix/local[8558]: 69563EC738: to=<myname@mydomain.eu>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "myname")
```

(Of course I substituted real email and domain names for fake ones here)

Answer (score 2):

You should read log files of your MTA to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Sorry, I am not vey much at home with this. I'm runnin Ubuntu and I have postfix and mailutils installed. How would I go about reading the log files?

Comment: OK, i figured it out. Here are some interesting things (check my original post)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some examples of your code?

I think you forgot to pass valid headers, there are some email servers that reject every email without X-Mailer set for example.

Comment: Just curios. Can you provide example of such MTA?

Comment: Well, I don't know if Wordpress is passing valid headers. I think it should be. Basically, I want to get Wordpress to send me my forgotten password email.